# Bluetooth to PC: Device, port & UUID

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluecove

I'm working on an app on Android that is supposed to connect to a custom device via Bluetooth, but in order to emulate that device (which I don't have yet), I made a simulator on PC, using Java's Bluecove.

However, I'm having a hard time figuring out the different connection's method.

First, on Android, we discover the device (here, a PC), then:

-We have the "UUID" solution, as explain in [android sdk doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(java.util.UUID)).

-Or the "Port" solution, as proposed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562217/android-bluetooth-chat-with-pc-serially).

The second one seems more natural to me, as I don't quite understand what is a UUID in this scenario.

I do understand that we need to connect to a port of a device, but what does the UUID have to do with that? Why don't we need to specify it in the second solution?

If someone could give me a clue, that would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

bluetooth communication is communication with service, so when you wanna connect to device you are attempting to connect to service,and uuid is number with which we connect to service, like ok, i wanna this uuid(this service).